# How do I correctly restrict a generic interface to extend Number class in Java and be able to run it in another class?

Tags: java, generics, interface, extends, subtyping

Am trying to understand how to extend an interface and use it in another class but each time the compiler throws a casting error. I have tried using wildcard in the method printResult but it does not work. What could be the issue here? It only works with Integer.

```
public interface Computable <T extends Number>
{
    public T compute(T x, T y);    
}

------------------------------------------------------------

public class TestComputable
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Computable<Float> comp;
        comp = (x, y) -> x + y;
        printResult(comp);
    }
}

public static void printResult(Computable compIn)
{
    System.out.println("The result is: " + compIn.compute(10, 5));
}
```

Comment: "It only works for Integer" that'll be because you're passing it Integer parameters.

Comment: @AndyTurner Even if I change it 10.1 and 5.2, the result is the same. It throws the same error. Do you know what when wrong? It doesn't work on Float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will only work for Integer because you're passing in Integer arguments to the Computable.

If you want to pass in e.g. "the Float equivalent of the Integer", you need to pass in a Function to convert the Integer to a Float; more generally, if you want to pass in "the T equivalent of the Integer", you need to pass in a Function to convert the Integer to a T:

```
public static <T extends Number> void printResult(Computable<T> compIn, Function<? super Integer, ? extends T> fn)
{
    System.out.println("The result is: " + compIn.compute(fn.apply(10), fn.apply(5)));
}
```

and invoke like:

```
printResult(comp, Integer::floatValue);
```

Alternatively, you can pass in the correctly-typed arguments explicitly:

```
public static <T extends Number> void printResult(Computable<T> compIn, T a, T b) {
    // ... Something with compln.compute(a, b)
}
```

and invoke like:

```
printResult(comp, 10.f, 5.f);
```

The only way you can make this work without passing in additional parameters is to only accept a `Computable` that can accept any Number, or at least that can accept arguments of the type you are passing in:

```
public static void printResult(Computable<Number> compIn) { ... }
public static void printResult(Computable<Integer> compIn) { ... }
public static void printResult(Computable<? super Integer> compIn) { ... }
```

Comment: Hmmm, can the method be changed to infer the type when comp is passed into printResult?

Comment: Thanks for the various solutions. I guess I cannot do it similar to the way generic classes uses the <T extends Number> in the method.

Answer (score 2):

This is where the compiler actually tried to help you by emitting a warning about using a raw type: if you change the `printResult` method to use the proper type argument as follows:

```
public static void printResult(Computable<Float> compIn) { // instead of Computable compIn
```

then the compiler would have shown an error at compile time:

```
// Now the compiler throws error:
// the method compute(Float, Float) is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)
System.out.println("The result is: " + compIn.compute(10, 5));
```

This is why you should always avoid using raw types, the compiler can infer the proper binding of types.

Now that we have the compilation error message, we know what the problem is: the arguments `10` and `5` are `int` values, while the interface `Computable` expects `Float` values, so you can fix them to be treated as float values:

```
System.out.println("The result is: " + compIn.compute(10f, 5f));
```

Comment: @M Anouti Is there a way to change the method such that the compiler can make inferences and choose the correct data type to execute?

Comment: @JinYuChan The problem is that the compiler can only see `10` and `5` as `Integer`, while you expect a `Float` as type argument. So you should use `10f` and `5f`. It's either this or that :)